# WebSockets (JS,Apache,PHP)

Tags: networking, websocket, streaming, mod-proxy

I'm simply trying to get a WebSocket handshake down using javascript, apache, php.

For clarity before we begin:

- *Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)*
- *PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14*
- *Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)*
- I have both port 8080 and 8090 open and accepting on both IPv4/IPv6

**{CLIENT}**

When you go to example.com:8080 it will run the following JS on initialization.

//JS

```
function init(){
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8090"); //redirect on port 8090
    socket.send("Here's some text that the server is waiting for");
}
```

**{SERVER}**

//APACHE (virtual host config) *mod_proxy & mod_proxy_wstunnel are installed

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>                                                            
        ServerName example:8090                                
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/uploader                                                                                                                    
        ProxyPass "/sockets/" "http://example.com:8090"                                                                                            
</VirtualHost>
```

//PHP (/var/www/vhost/uploader/sockets/index.php)

```
<?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    $ip = 'example.com';
    socket_bind($sock, $ip);
    socket_connect($sock, $ip, 8090);
    $request = 'GET / HTTP/1.1' . "\r\n" .
               'Host: example.com' . "\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($sock, $request);
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Where I'm confused is the fact that Apache is doing the binding/listening of the socket and port so I don't know how to access it within PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Your Server Side PHP page must include code to listen to the port for a websocket connection. Apache server listens for HTTP requests not for websocket connections. Give [socket.io](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/) a try. There's an implementation for PHP [here](https://github.com/rase-/socket.io-php-emitter).

Another option is [socketo.me](http://socketo.me/).

G00d 1uck.

Comment: Okay yea I wasn't sure if Apache passed it over via some PHP variable. So really apache (mod_proxy) strictly forwards the request and keeps the "connection-alive" and allows you to set-config on client connections, you would still `$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)` in php and all that.

Comment: Yea I've seen socket.io, I've written my own socket web-server before in C, I'm just new to these apache directives so still learning and getting a little lost since there is like 0 examples online I feel like.